# Getting Data through PHP via AJAX not working

Tags: php, ajax

I am having problems getting data from a server using a combination of generating the data through PHP and using an ajax method to retrieve it.

I want to get the data through GET within receive.php that calls get_data.php

My ajax function located within receive.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
       url: '<website>/get_data.php',
       data: {
          format: 'json'
       },
       error: function() {
          $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
       },
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);

       },
       type: 'GET'
    });
</script>
```

get_data.php:

```
<?php
...
$data = array('a','b','c');
$data = json_encode($long);
echo $data;

?>
```

When I run receive.php I get an ajax error: GET 404 error.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think it's error in your path.. Just copy the AJAX URL path and paste it into new tab if you got 404. Then we analyze that error in path

Comment: @kannan I pasted the ajax path <website>/get_data.php?callback=jQuery111309272575108334422_1447525665922&format=json&_=1447525665923 it returns the data

Comment: Check the developer console in the browser.

Comment: You could use Firebug to evaluate the issue further. Additionally, are you using relative or absolute paths?

Comment: @Jan I am using absolute paths